# Creating & Updating Activity/Conversation in goHighLevel using API

Tags: api

I am willing to use goHighLevel `CREATE & UPDATE API endpoints` to create activities with type as CALL.
I am using `https://services.leadconnectorhq.com/conversations/{conversationId}` endpoint to `CREATE & UPDATE` the conversations.
This is what i am passing in the body:

```
{
  "locationId": "2ZL9teeeeeeeeDPVZ",
  "unreadCount": 1,
  "starred": true,
  "type": 3,
  "status": "completed",
  "lastMessage": {
    "type": "call",
    "call": {
      "status": "completed",
      "duration": 300,
      "recordingUrl": "https://example.com/recording.mp3"
    }
  }
}
```

But I am struggling with it, as it gives the success response and creates an empty activity in goHighLevel, and the same for the UPDATE, it returns the success response but no updation.

I need help with to how to create an activity on call arrival and update the activity on call ended. There is no explanation provided on the documentation (https://highlevel.stoplight.io/docs/integrations)

Comment: How did you get the new Access Token each time?